# What is the requirement of bsc archive full node

Tags: bsc

I want to run a bsc archive node with aws ec2 with spot instance. What would be the disk space/cpu/ram requirement? Any tips on how to spend least amount of money?

Comment: _Any tips on how to spend least amount of money?_ you can try to cache HDD disk with a small SSD if you use `bcache` kernel module, however it is not usable for syncing, only to keep the node running. So you can sync on fast server, and then move data to inexpensive `bcache` enabled server. I am using this setup to run archival node.

Comment: @Nulik, thanks so much for your suggestion. I didn't have a experience running a full archive node yet. Did you have some article that helps me on how to setup a full archive node on EC2?

Comment: @hg62819hg you don't have to run archival node, it is just a way to cut on SSD storage. Ethereum stores data in Merkle Trie, this data structure presents random data access pattern which is very unfriendly with slow disks. Due to SSD latency of only 50 microseconds, you can only have 20,000 accesses to disk per second, but there is also CPU running spending its time, so the speed of SSD is critical

Comment: I don't have articles

Comment: so, if you are like running a trading bot, you need PCI v4 SSD , but if it is just for non-critical data extraction, like a dApp or something, `bcache` will help

Comment: @Nulik, I actually need to run a archive node. Since I need to query some function results based on block number. I need roughly 300Million such queries... Would you teach me how to set up such archive node? What steps shall I follow? Thanks so much! What kind of budget do you expect if i run on AWS EC2 with spot instance?